# Why do routing tables in routers have gateway set to IP address of their own interface

Tags: networking, router, routing, gateway, routing-table

In the following [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Default_gateway#Multi-router), the routers have a gateway set to the IP address of one of its own interfaces. Following diagram shows the network topology where the routing table of Router 2 is visible which has the one gateway set to 172.161.1.1 which is eth1 IP address - [Network Topology diagram](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c6/Sample_network.svg)

Q.1 Why is this done? Isn't gateway supposed to be IP address of the next hop?

Q.2 Is this same as putting 0.0.0.0 in the gateway field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a matter of notation.

Usually such entries represent "on-link" routes aka "connected" routes, i.e. networks which are directly accessible on that interface **without** any gateway. In other words, a local subnet.

However, different operating systems, and even different *user interfaces*, have different ways of writing down such routes.

- Solaris and OpenBSD "netstat -rn" uses the interface's local address (and no 'G' flag, indicating that this is a non-gateway route). And it also doesn't bother displaying netmasks.

  ```
  $ netstat -rn
    Destination           Gateway           Flags  Ref     Use     Interface
  -------------------- -------------------- ----- ----- ---------- ---------
  default              192.168.1.1          UG        5  280064959 aggr1
  192.168.1.0          192.168.1.7          U         3   11962636 aggr1
  ```
- The same "netstat -rn" on Linux, however, uses 0.0.0.0 instead because the actual interface is stored in a separate field.

  ```
  $ netstat -rn
  Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
  0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 eno1
  192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 eno1
  ```
- FreeBSD and NetBSD will show that the gateway is a 'link':

  ```
  $ netstat -rn
  Destination        Gateway            Flags    Refs      Use    Mtu Interface
  default            192.168.1.1        UGS         -        -      -  wm1
  192.168.1/24       link#2             UC          -        -      -  wm1
  192.168.1.8        link#2             UHl         -        -      -  lo0
  ```
- Linux nowadays uses an entirely different set of CLI tools; "ip route show" uses a flexible output format and simply omits the "via <gateway_addr>" part when showing such routes.

  ```
  $ ip -4 route show
  default via 192.168.1.1 dev eno1
  192.168.1.0/24 dev eno1
  ```
- Cisco IOS omits the gateway and says "directly connected" (plus the 'C' flag):

  ```
  Cisco1760# show ip route
  Codes: C - connected, S - static, R - RIP, M - mobile, B - BGP
         D - EIGRP, EX - EIGRP external, O - OSPF, [...]

       10.0.0.0/8 is variably subnetted, 73 subnets, 4 masks
  O       10.147.241.56/30 [110/3] via 10.147.18.1, 09:35:51, FastEthernet0/0
  C       10.147.241.60/30 is directly connected, Serial1/1
  C       10.147.18.0/24 is directly connected, FastEthernet0/0
  ```
- Windows says "On-link":

  ```
  C:\> route print
  Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
            0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0    192.168.1.254    192.168.1.100     35
        192.168.1.0    255.255.255.0         On-link     192.168.1.100    291
  ```
- Mikrotik RouterOS puts the interface name *in* the gateway field (plus showing the 'C' flag for 'connected'):

  ```
  > /ip route print detail
   1 A S  dst-address=0.0.0.0/0 gateway=192.168.1.1 distance=1
          scope=30 target-scope=10
   2 ADC  dst-address=192.168.1.0/24 pref-src=192.168.1.9 gateway=ether1
          distance=0 scope=10
  ```

Answer (score 0):

the router Interface IS the next hop. Enterprise-grade routers often have many interfaces for many networks, and will route traffic between them.

So if a PC wants to connect to a file share on the storage network, the PC's gateway is the routers interface on the PC network, and the next hop is that same router's interface for the Storage network. You can think of the "Gateway" in this context as the "Exit Interface" used to reach a particular network.

The only difference between this scenario an another where the next hop is upstream, is that the router in question has interfaces on both networks. you could as easily imagine that they are hosted by two different routers, and the gateway is an interface on that router. The situations are functionally the same.

Comment: `the router Interface IS the next hop.` I think this is a bad way to put it. We don't consider there to be a hop if the destination is directly reachable. (Note that the OP is asking about the router itself, not some other host that makes use of the router.) (Even if you count each node instead of each action of "crossing/jumping over" one as a hop, the next hop would be some other host, not an interface.)